# Sound differences between aux and bluetooth audio

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth, speakers

(I have actually had a lot issues with sound quality with my new Dell XPS 15, leading me down endless self help articles and constant audio driver uninstalls and updates. However, this forum isn't for customer support, so I have a more general question.)

Anyways, I started using aux connection to my speaker recently because I could not stop the periodic crackling that my bluetooth connection created, but the aux connection seems to have elevated and distorted bass compared to the bluetooth connection. Note, I am not a staunch audio person; these differences are very noteable and have very negative effects on the quality. I am curious why I seem to have such different sounds coming from my speaker depending on whether I use a bluetooth connection or an aux cord. Even if they use a different medium for sending audio, they should be sending the exact same information to the speaker, right? Is it typical for bluetooth and aux to give different sounds? If I were to, for example, send the audio signal through a thunderbolt port with other data, could I expect another audio experience?

Comment: Short answer: Yes. Bluetooth and analog audio connections can sound very different depending on many different factors, both hardware and software.

Comment: Different connections, different DACs